# Is it correct to say "have a pass on something" instead of "make a pass on something"?

Tags: phrases

I saw such phrases used by some guy:

> make a pass on something

or

> take a pass on something

What I want to convey with this phrase is something like

> browse something (like writing or blueprints, etc) from start to end, maybe quickly. Usually aim to correct errors or refine the stuff.

Like in the following sentence:

> I just finished my thesis, can you please make a pass on it and correct the grammar errors there?

Somehow I just want to know whether it's also correct to say

> have a pass on something.

Is it okay to put it this way? Or it's mostly unseen before?

Comment: Could you add what you think the phrases 'make/take/have a pass' would mean?

Comment: If by *take a pass* you mean *abstain from offering an opinion*, most people would probably just say *I'll pass on that one [that subject / question requiring a response].* You could say *I'll take a pass on that*, but note that ***making** a pass on [a potential sexual partner]* is a completely different usage. Unless you edit to clarify the sense you intend, this question will be closed as "Unclear".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yeah, sorry for being so sloppy. Just added one sample sentence there.

Comment: Okay, well I've retracted my closevote. I don't recognise your example usage though. Are you perhaps conflating ***pass*** with ***parse**?* I suggest you just switch to *...can you please **run through** it?* (or even more informal, ***eyeball** it*). And ask any future questions like this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, actually I saw the usage of "make a pass on" from one email. I think that's how the guy uses the phrase. For me I never used it before. So I really don't know whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Define "correct". The purpose of language is to communicate, so arguably if you didn't understand it it would be an incorrect usage from someone talking to you. Or *me,* come to that - except your cited usage wouldn't bother me because it's contextually likely I can completely ignore the bit about *making a pass*, since it's really just a bit of "deferential circumlocution" (meaningless fluff) before explicitly coming out with the *actual* request *(Please **correct the errors**)*. Probably implying *...without going to too much trouble*.

Comment: Not at all; never. Please notice, if you think it “common to see such phrases” you’re not moving in a world of British or American English, anyway.
“Make” and “take” and “have” a pass “*on*” are not comparable and none of them would work with your example.
“browse something (like writing or blueprints, etc) from start to end, maybe quickly. Usually aim to correct errors or refine the stuff” suggests “Make a pass *at*” which is wholly different.
Do you see no difference between “I saw the usage of ‘make a pass on’ from one email” and “It's common to see…”, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Actually I'm really not in a English-speaking country. Somehow I thought I'm pretty used to the usage like this, but after thinking it carefully, I can't think of the place where I saw it second time except in the email. Thanks for point this out!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, now I more tend to think that this is only the way of how the *specific* guy express it. Somehow I thought it's familiar to me without any reason. I will avoid using it this way in the future.

Comment: I will hazard a guess that the *reason* you thought the usage was more common than native speakers would expect is partly because you hear it from other non-native speakers *in your location*. Most of whom are presumably native speakers of the same language as you. All of you would be likely to make the *same* mistakes in certain contexts - different to those often made by speakers of *other* languages. But because the ones *you* hear are likely to reflect your "native" ideas about vocabulary and syntax, they'll feel more "natural" to you even though they're actually "wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that’s not an idiomatic way of asking for people to help make improvements to something like a thesis.

Consider *proofreading* or *review* instead. If you want something quick, you can ask someone to “look it over”.

> **proofread** *verb*
> Read (printer's proofs or other written or printed material) and mark any errors.
> ‘Final drafts of essays, assignments and lab reports are reviewed and proofread by highly knowledgable graduate students with refined writing skills.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proofread)
>
> **review** *verb*
> 1 Assess (something) formally with the intention of instituting change if necessary.
> ‘Every UK local authority website is reviewed and assessed against e-government and good practice criteria.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/review)
>
> **look-over** *noun*
> A quick inspection of something; a survey.
> ‘Most applications get a look-over for quality control by programmer colleagues.’
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/look-over)

Answer (score 1):

**make a pass**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+a+pass+at)

> the idiomatic uses of this includes flirting, attempts at something,
>   and flying over X.

I suggest modifications to your sample question:

> I just finished my thesis, can you please X it and correct the grammar
>   errors there?

X = read it, look over, brutally and unmercifully review